# Swift4. Custom view not being displayed in custom init

Tags: swift, uiview

Can anyone point out what is the issue with the following piece of code.?

```
 class CustomView: UIView {
        init(_ i:Int, _ view:UIView){

            super.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: i*300, width:Int(view.frame.size.width) , height: 300))
            for i in stride(from: 0, to: 3, by: 1){
                var view = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: (Int(self.frame.size.width/2-50)), y: i*00, width: 100, height: 100))

                switch(i%3){
                case 0:
                    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                    break;
                case 1:
                    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
                    break;
                case 2:
                    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

                }

                self.addSubview(view)


            }

 }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    print("not required to implement requiredInit here")


}
```

I am trying to display 3 different colored views based on the modulus operator. For some reason however only the last one with orange color is being displayed. The first two do not show up. The code doesn't crash either. 
Do i need to move the custom logic into the required init.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the line where you are initializing `view`. `i*00` is **always** 0.

Comment: Horrible Typo on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check like below :

```
init(_ i:Int, _ view:UIView){
    super.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: i*300, width:Int(view.frame.size.width) , height: 300))
    for i in stride(from: 0, to: 3, by: 1){
        var subview = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: (Int(self.frame.size.width/2-50)), y: i*100, width: 100, height: 100))

        switch(i%3){
        case 0:
            subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            break;
        case 1:
            subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            break;
        case 2:
            subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        view.addSubview(subview)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok i found the issue. Still doesn't answer the question as to why the third view was working fine despite being i*00

Comment: Your y is i*00 so always y is 0. views are displaying one over the other

Comment: *facepalm*.. Sorry about that.. And thanks. Will accept the answer.

Comment: Change it ti i*100 you will see the difference